# Having problems with httpost json string through vb.net

Tags: vb.net, json, http-post

Here's my code that I am using to send as post to the specified URL.

```
Dim url = "http://www.abc.com/new/process"

Dim data As String = nvc.ToString
Dim postAddress = New Uri(Url)

Dim request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(postAddress), HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/json"
Dim postByteData As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
request.ContentLength = postByteData.Length

Using postStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    postStream.Write(postByteData, 0, postByteData.Length)
End Using

Using resp = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim reader = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
    result.Response = reader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

Now the problem is I don't get any exception here, but the response I'm supposed to get after posting (success or error) is not coming to my end. The URL is fine, I checked it. Am I sending it the right way?

Comment: I get the response "This stream does not support seek operations."

Comment: am i sending the json string the right way? Cause i use the same when iam sending xml or normal string and it works fine. Is there some different way to send JSON string from vb.net?

Comment: @slaks .. thanks a lot for merging accounts.

Comment: HTTP is HTTP.  The content of the POST body doesn't matter at all.  Your code is correct.  (As long as `nvc.ToString` returns valid JSON)

Comment: What's the exception's stack trace?

Comment: You say 'I don't get any exception here' and (in the comment) 'I get the response "This stream does not support seek operations." '. I haven't dealt with JSON servers, but that sounds like the error is occurring at the server you're talking to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that ReadToEnd method on StreamReader internally uses the Length property. This will be null if the server doesn't send a length in the http header. Try using memory stream and a buffer instead:

```
    Dim url = "http://my.posturl.com"

    Dim data As String = nvc.ToString()
    Dim postAddress = New Uri(url)

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(postAddress)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    Dim postByteData As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
    request.ContentLength = postByteData.Length

    Using postStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        postStream.Write(postByteData, 0, postByteData.Length)
    End Using

    Using resp = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim b As Byte() = Nothing
        Using stream As Stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                Dim count As Integer = 0
                Do
                    Dim buf As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
                    count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024)
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, count)
                Loop While stream.CanRead AndAlso count > 0
                b = ms.ToArray()
            End Using
        End Using
        Console.WriteLine("Response: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Using
```